# Multiple Queries and Loops within CPT Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, query

I have a Custom Post Type called 'properties', and have set up an Archive page to display posts within that category.

Essentially, the Archive page needs to contain 3 different query types; the first to display search results of posts within the CPT, the second to make results sortable (queried through a drop-down menu that interrogates Custom Field meta values), and the third to display all posts within the CPT.

I'm not sure how to structure the queries and loops though - all the queries work individually, but I'm struggling how to set up the If/Else statements to make them work within one archive page, so would be grateful for any advice you might have!

**Query 1: Search Results**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'properties',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'property_size',
    'value' => $_GET['size'],
    'compare' => '>='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'property_rent',
    'value' => $_GET['budget-from'],
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'property_rent',
        'value' => $_GET['budget-to'],
    'compare' => '<=',
    'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    )

       ),
   'paged' => $paged 

);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Query 2: Sortable Posts within CPT**

```
if($_POST['square-sort-select'] == 0):

$select = $_POST['square-sort-select'];
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=> 'properties',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'property_rent',
    'orderby' => 'property_rent',
    'order' => DESC
));

; elseif($_POST['square-sort-select'] == 1):

    $select = $_POST['square-sort-select'];
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=> 'properties',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'property_rent',
    'orderby' => 'property_rent',
    'order' => ASC
));

; elseif($_POST['square-sort-select'] == 2):

    $select = $_POST['square-sort-select'];
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=> 'properties',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => DESC
));
```

**Query 3: All Posts within CPT**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query();
$query->query('post_type=properties&posts_per_page=6&paged='.$paged);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of queries! Have you considered running the query once and using something like [mixitup](http://mixitup.io/) or [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to sort your results?